# How to show a javascript alert just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

See, this is my code for the alert:

```js
function Alerta() {
  var person = prompt("¡Recuerda!:Todos Los Titulos Abren El Menu!\nCual es tu nombre?", "Goku");
    
    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML =
        "" + person + "";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onLoad="Alerta()" id="Inicio">
</body>
```

The problem is that it shows up every time I enter in the page, refresh the page...or blink, so... I want it to do this: when you write a name and click "accept" it saves the name and the alert is never shown again, and when you click "cancel" it will show it every time you enter the page. Help please?

Comment: you have to consider using cookies, store the name in a cookie, and check every time if cookie is present

Answer (score 2):

You could use `localStorage` to save the persons name between sessions, then only prompt if the person value is not set in `localStorage`. If you need backwards compatibility you can use cookies in place of `localStorage`

```js
function Alerta() {
  // get the value from localStorage
  var person = localStorage.person
  if (!person) {
    // person has not been set so ask the user
    person = prompt("¡Recuerda!:Todos Los Titulos Abren El Menu!\nCual es tu nombre?", "Goku");
    // set the person value in localStorage for next time
    localStorage.person = person
  }
  // set the value of your intro
  document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = person;
}
```

Comment: Dude... you saved my life :v

Comment: as a last question what do i do if i want to erase the name of localstorage with, lets say... a botton?

Comment: localStorage.removeItem('person');

Comment: The full documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Answer (score 0):

When they enter a name, save it to something that persists across pages (like a cookie or local storage), and if it's already set, suppress the prompt when the page loads.

Comment: im pretty sure that that would work if i could understand... im a noob on this :v for the time...